# php array searching with keys

Tags: php, arrays, search

Suppose an array like the following:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [x] => binginb
        )

    [b] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [x] => dibdab
        )

)
```

Now I would like to access this array based on its contents, so `id` and `x` in this case.

It would be nice here to be able to do something like

```
 $i = array_search(5,array_column($a,'id'));
 $stuff = dostuff($a[$i]['x']);
```

but that doesn't work since `$a[1]` is an undefined offset.

Is it possible to do anything like this without mutating the original array?

Comment: This might make sense for an `id`, but what would you expect back when there are multiple results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array_search()` returns the index of the result of `array_column()`. You could use [`array_keys()`](https://php.net/array_keys) to find the key for this index:

```
$a = [
   'a' => ['id' => 3, 'x' => 'binginb'],
   'b' => ['id' => 5, 'x' => 'dibdab'],
   ];
$i = array_search(5, array_column($a,'id'));
$key = array_keys($a)[$i]; // get the key at the $i index.
$stuff = dostuff($a[$key]['x']); // Here, $a[$key]['x'] = 'dibdab'
```

Note that [`array_search()`](https://php.net/array_search) could return `FALSE` if the value is not found. You could test the result (using a strict comparison) before to use it.

```
$i = array_search(5, array_column($a,'id'));
if ($i !== false) {
    $key = array_keys($a)[$i]; // get the key at the $i index.
    $stuff = dostuff($a[$key]['x']); // Here, $a[$key]['x'] = 'dibdab'
}
```

Comment: And to extend the technique slightly, if you want to get all matches for something, `('id' == 5)`, you could do `$k = array_keys...` instead of `array_search` then `print_r($a[array_keys($a)[$k[1]]]['x']);` will be "'x' for the second element matching "ID = 5" in $a"

Answer (score 2):

Use `array_column` to re-index the array by `id`:

```
$new = array_column($a, 'x', 'id');
```

Then to search for `5`, just:

```
echo $new[5];
```

If you may have more than just `x`:

```
$new = array_column($a, null, 'id');
```

Then:

```
echo $new[5]['x'];
```

If you only do this once:

```
echo array_column($a, 'x', 'id')[5];
```

Or:

```
echo array_column($a, null, 'id')[5]['x'];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wish to be limited by PHP built-in functions then try this out:

```
<?php
function dostuff( $var1 )
{
    print_r($var1);
}

$a = [
   'a' => ['id' => 3, 'x' => 'binginb'],
   'b' => ['id' => 5, 'x' => 'dibdab'],
];

array_map( // 2: pass each element from the result from array_filter to dostuff()
    'dostuff',
    array_filter( // 1: filter $a based on the criteria defined in the anonymous function
        $a,
        function($item){
            return $item['id'] === 5;
        }
    )
);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 5
    [x] => dibdab
)
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it will help you,

```
<?php
$array = array(
    'a' => array(
        'id' => 3,
        'x' => 'binginb',
    ),
    'b' => array(
        'id' => 5,
        'x' => 'dibdab',
    )
);

$i = array_column($array,'x','id');
```

> // Output of `$i`
>
> Array (
>       [3] => binginb
>       [5] => dibdab )

```
$stuff = dostuff($i[5]); // $i[5] return dibdab
```